# Regex to extract Paragraph from a pdf which extends to another page

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

I am new to extracting data from PDF files. I need help regarding extraction of paragraph content which contains a particular keyword. The issue I face is that the paragraph in which the keyword is, extends to another page, with the page separator `\r\n\x0c` and all the paragraphs are separated with `\r\n` pattern.
The below is the attachment that will make you understand the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pHyN.png)

**Here is the link to the pdf**
https://www.jpmorganchase.com/content/dam/jpmc/jpmorgan-chase-and-co/investor-relations/documents/annualreport-2022.pdf

I need to extract the content from **"As these events…."** to **"economy is safe and secure."**

**I will provide you with a small chunk of or the same chunk of text extracted formatted from pdf.**

"\r\n\r\nAcross the globe, 2022 was another year of significant challenges: from a terrible war in Ukraine and growing geopolitical tensions -- particularly with China -- to a politically divided America. Almost all nations felt the effects of global economic uncertainty, including higher energy and food prices, mounting inflation rates and volatile markets, and, of course, COVID-19's lingering impacts. While all these experiences and associated turmoil have serious ramifications on our company, colleagues, clients and the countries in which we do business, their consequences on the world at large -- with the extreme suffering of the Ukrainian people and the potential restructuring of the global order -- are far more important.\r\nAs these events unfold, America remains divided within its borders, and its global leadership role is being challenged outside of its borders. Nevertheless, this is the moment when we should put aside our differences and work with other Western nations to come together in defense of democracy and essential\r\n2\r\n\r\n\x0cfreedoms, including free enterprise. During other times of great crisis, we have seen America, in partnership with other countries around the globe, unite for a common cause. This is that moment again, when our country needs to work across public and private sectors to lead while improving American competitiveness -- which also means re-establishing the American promise of providing equal access to opportunity for all. JPMorgan Chase, a company that historically has worked across borders and boundaries, will do its part to ensure the global economy is safe and secure.\r\n"

Please help me by providing the regex for extracting this content.

**paragraph_pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\r\n)([A-Z][^\n]+(\r\n\x0c(?!\n)[^\n]+)*)')**

I tried providing this regex, but it only gives me paragraph content which are available only in single page.
I need a starting pattern of '\r\n' which start with [A-Z] and ending pattern of '\r\n' which ends with (.), furthermore I also need to add the case of page separation that I have provided above.

The code that I am using is:

```
import re
import textract

def extract_paragraphs_from_pdf(pdf_path, keywords):
 
paragraph_pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\n)[A-Z].*(?:(?:\n|\r\n\x0c)(?!\n).*)*\.(?=\r\n)')

 
extracted_paragraphs = []
pdf_text = textract.process(pdf_path, method='pdftotext').decode('utf-8')
temp = repr(pdf_text)

#with open('sa.txt','w') as f:
#    f.write(temp)

matches = paragraph_pattern.findall(pdf_text)

for paragraph in matches:
    if any(f' {keyword} ' in paragraph[0].lower() for keyword in keywords):
        extracted_paragraphs.append(paragraph[0].strip())

return extracted_paragraphs

pdf_file_path = './jp.pdf'
search_keywords = ['partnership']

result_paragraphs = extract_paragraphs_from_pdf(pdf_file_path, 
search_keywords)

for res in result_paragraphs:
    print("-->>",res)
```

Comment: Hi, removing or replacing the page separator '\r\n\x0c' does not work?

Comment: Well removing or replacing the page separator is not possible, as I have to extract the same from 500 documents.

Comment: Not taking the word to find into account, perhaps like this? `(?<=\r\n)[A-Z].*(?:(?:\n|\r\n\x0c)(?!\n).*)*\.(?=\r\n)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tried your approach but it doesn't seem to print anything.

Comment: So the paragraphs are preceded and followed by `\r\n` and the lines in the paragraphs are divided by just `\n`? Can you add the code that you are using to the question? And maybe a link to the pdf instead of an image?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes you are right, the paragraphs are preceded and followed by \r\n and the lines in the paragraph are divided by \n.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have provided the code and pdf link.

Comment: Also, this part in the code `paragraph[0].lower()` gets the first character. It should be `paragraph.lower()`

Comment: @airmon Try using `paragraph_pattern = re.compile(r'\n([A-Z][^.]*(?:\.(?!\n)[^.]*)*\.)(?=\n)')` and then `if any(f' {keyword} ' in paragraph.lower() for keyword in keywords):
            extracted_paragraphs.append(paragraph.strip())` That should give you 3 results.

Comment: You might also try `\r?\n` instead of only `\n` like `paragraph_pattern = re.compile(r'\r?\n([A-Z][^.]*(?:\.(?!\r?\n)[^.]*)*\.)(?=\r?\n)')`

Comment: @Thefourthbird nothing works. Still no progress. IDK what is the issue.

Comment: @airmon I am running this code on Linux https://ideone.com/oYLTNR

Comment: @Thefourthbird 
Well first of all you have to install the textract package to your system.
cmd: pip install textract

Secondly when in the loop of "matches" you have to add paragraph[0].lower() and paragraph[0].strip(), because the match is a list of tuples, and it will have only one whole value of paragraph to extract from.

Then I guess your code might run without any error, but I doubt there will any output as of the regex used. Again if you encounter any error you can use my regex expression provided in stackoverflow.

Comment: @airmon I have that package installed, I used that link to just share the code (I does not work on ideone) Using `re.findall` gives back the value of the capture group, which in this case is just a single capture group, so there are no tuples, and that is why you should just use `paragraph.lower()` or else you will get the first character of the string. Did you try the code that I shared here? https://ideone.com/8PLntL

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the result https://imgur.com/a/Hk9pu2G

Comment: @Thefourthbird The output that you are getting is correct, but when I run the same thing it doesn't any output.

Comment: @airmon Are you running it with the same exact code?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Okay It runs, finally!!! Thank you so much for your quick responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that instead of using `paragraph[0].lower()` you should use `paragraph.lower()` or else you would get the first character of the string instead.

Using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will return the capture group 1 values in a list

You could use a pattern with a capture group:

```
\r?\n([A-Z][^.]*(?:\.(?!\r?\n)[^.]*)*\.)(?=\r?\n)
```

- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z][^.]*` Match an uppercase char A-Z and optional chars other than a dot
  - `(?:\.(?!\r?\n)[^.]*)*` Then repeat matching any character, and only dots that are not directly followed by a newline
  - `\.` Match a dot
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?=\r?\n)` Positive lookahead, assert a newline directly to the right

The updated code:

```
import re
import textract
 
def extract_paragraphs_from_pdf(pdf_path, keywords):
    paragraph_pattern = re.compile(r'\r?\n([A-Z][^.]*(?:\.(?!\r?\n)[^.]*)*\.)(?=\r?\n)')
 
    extracted_paragraphs = []
    pdf_text = textract.process(pdf_path, method='pdftotext').decode('utf-8')
 
    matches = paragraph_pattern.findall(pdf_text)
    for paragraph in matches:
        if any(f' {keyword} ' in paragraph.lower() for keyword in keywords):
            extracted_paragraphs.append(paragraph.strip())
    return extracted_paragraphs
 
 
pdf_file_path = './jp.pdf'
search_keywords = ["partnership"]
 
result_paragraphs = extract_paragraphs_from_pdf(pdf_file_path, search_keywords)
for res in result_paragraphs:
    print("-->>", res)
```

The result (you want the first, but note that you get 3 results as you are filtering on  `partnership` )

[image]

Comment: It's perfect, basically I needed to extract the paragraphs that contained the keyword given by the user; in this case, the keyword was "partnership."
So the output that you got is the one I needed.